# XSLT loop - values on all iterations being assigned to each of the specific node

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having a problem with the XSLT with for-each.  The values on all iterations seems to be retrieved and assigned to specific node per iteration.

**XML**

```html
<TABLE>
   <HEADER xmlns="">
      <DETAIL xmlns="">
         <value1 xmlns="">value1</value1>
         <value2 xmlns="">value2</value2>
      </DETAIL>
   <DETAIL xmlns="">
         <value1 xmlns="">value3</value1>
         <value2 xmlns="">value4</value2>
      </DETAIL>
   </HEADER>
</TABLE>
```

**XSLT**

```html
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="Json">
            <xsl:for-each select="*:HEADER/*:DETAIL">
                <xsl:element name="array">
                    <xsl:element name="test1"><xsl:value-of select="../../*:HEADER/*:DETAIL/*:value1"/></xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="test2"><xsl:value-of select="../../*:HEADER/*:DETAIL/*:value2"/></xsl:element>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the output I get:

Actual

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Json>
 <array>
  <test1>value1 value3</test1>
  <test2>value2 value4</test2>
 </array>
 <array>
  <test1>value1 value3</test1>
  <test2>value2 value4</test2>
 </array>
</Json>
```

Expected

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Json>
 <array>
  <test1>value1</test1>
  <test2>value2</test2>
 </array>
 <array>
  <test1>value3</test1>
  <test2>value4</test2>
 </array>
</Json>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this part:

```
<xsl:element name="test1"><xsl:value-of select="../../*:HEADER/*:DETAIL/*:value1"/></xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="test2"><xsl:value-of select="../../*:HEADER/*:DETAIL/*:value2"/></xsl:element>
```

to:

```
<xsl:element name="test1"><xsl:value-of select="*:value1"/></xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="test2"><xsl:value-of select="*:value2"/></xsl:element>
```

What you have now goes up to the ancestor `TABLE` and selects **all** its `value1` or `value2` descendants.

---

**Note**:

1. `xsl:element` should be used when the name of the element needs to
   be calculated. In your case, you could simplify the stylesheet by
   using *literal result elements* , e.g.

   ```
   <test1><xsl:value-of select="*:value1"/></test1>
   <test2><xsl:value-of select="*:value2"/></test2>
   ```
2. Using a wildcard as the namespace prefix can lead to unpredicted results; you should limit such practice to the extremely rare cases where the namespace of the incoming XML is unknown in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a complete/short solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="HEADER">
    <Json>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Json>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="DETAIL">
    <array>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </array>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="DETAIL/*">
    <xsl:element name="test{position()}"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<TABLE>
    <HEADER xmlns="">
        <DETAIL xmlns="">
            <value1 xmlns="">value1</value1>
            <value2 xmlns="">value2</value2>
        </DETAIL>
        <DETAIL xmlns="">
            <value1 xmlns="">value3</value1>
            <value2 xmlns="">value4</value2>
        </DETAIL>
    </HEADER>
</TABLE>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Json>
   <array>
      <test1>value1</test1>
      <test2>value2</test2>
   </array>
   <array>
      <test1>value3</test1>
      <test2>value4</test2>
   </array>
</Json>
```

**Do note**:

1. No `<xsl:for-each>` is used -- in fact there is almost no scenario in XSLT where `<xsl:for-each>` is necessary. Using templates results in more powerful/polymorphic/flexible and reusable solutions.
2. The source XML document can have as many children of each `DETAIL` element, as needed (and each `DETAIL` element can have its own, different number of children) and the transformation generates correctly the element names (`test{N}`) in the result.

Enjoy!  :)